# mySQL,PHP,Json Error <br

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm getting an this error and cant seem to find the answer. Everything I've found on Google points at my php but Nothing seems to fix it. The JsonParser Class works for my register and login page.

The error is

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be
converted to JSONArray
```

Json Parser Class

```
  public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}



getLocalBus.class


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class GetLocalBus extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //gets JSONParser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

   TextView txt;

   double busLat;
   double busLng;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.get_local);


    txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView5);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetLocalBus.this);




    txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
    new readData().execute();

}
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://getData.php"; 

class readData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    boolean failure = false;

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();

       pDialog.setMessage("Getting Places...");
       pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
       pDialog.setCancelable(true);
       pDialog.show();
   }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {




       try {

           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat","37.3324083200000000"));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon","122.0304781500000000"));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dist","90"));

           Log.d("request!", "starting");
           // getting product details by making HTTP request
           JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   KEY_121, "POST", params);

           busLng = json.optDouble("business_lon",busLng);
           busLat = json.optDouble("business_lat",busLat);


       }
           finally{



           }
    return null;
       } 

   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

           if (pDialog != null) {
               pDialog.dismiss();
               pDialog = null;
           }

           txt.setText(""+busLng+" "+busLat);
   }

}


}
```

My php File

```
<?php


    if(isset($_GET['lat']) && isset($_GET['lon'])&& isset($_GET['dist'])){


        $db = new mysqli("myDatabaseUrl","username","password","DBname",0,"");

        $lat = $_GET['lat'];
        $lon = $_GET['lon'];
        $dist = $_GET['dist'];


        $search_sql = "SELECT business_id, business_lat, business_lon, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( " . $lat . " ) ) * cos( radians( " . $lon . " ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( " . $lat . " ) ) ) ) AS distance 
                        FROM myTable HAVING distance < " . $dist . " ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1 , 20";

        $search_results = $db->query($search_sql);

        if($search_results->num_rows){ 

            while ($search_results->fetch_assoc()){
                //array the the business data 
                $return_data[] = $search_results->fetch_array();
            }//end while

        }else{
            $return_data[] = array(); 
        }//end if


    }else{
        $return_data[] = array();
    }

    $bd_json = json_encode($return_data);

    $db->close();

    echo $bd_json;



?>
```

I Looked at the source code with my browser and don't see anything but Json. Here is the output.

```
[{"0":"3","business_id":"3","1":"37.393885","business_lat":"37.393885","2":"-122.078916","business_lon":"-122.078916","3":"23.0298400562551","distance":"23.0298400562551"},{"0":"5","business_id":"5","1":"37.394011","business_lat":"37.394011","2":"-122.095528","business_lon":"-122.095528","3":"23.0298400562551","distance":"23.0298400562551"},{"0":"7","business_id":"7","1":"37.390038","business_lat":"37.390038","2":"-122.042034","business_lon":"-122.042034","3":"23.0298400562551","distance":"23.0298400562551"},{"0":"9","business_id":"9","1":"32.723831","business_lat":"32.723831","2":"-117.168326","business_lon":"-117.168326","3":"23.0298400562551","distance":"23.0298400562551"},{"0":"11","business_id":"11","1":"47.557704","business_lat":"47.557704","2":"-122.284985","business_lon":"-122.284985","3":"23.0298400562551","distance":"23.0298400562551"},{"0":"13","business_id":"13","1":"47.614005","business_lat":"47.614005","2":"-122.313985","business_lon":"-122.313985","3":"23.0298400562551","distance":"23.0298400562551"},{"0":"15","business_id":"15","1":"47.672670","business_lat":"47.672670","2":"-122.354092","business_lon":"-122.354092","3":"23.0298400562551","distance":"23.0298400562551"},{"0":"17","business_id":"17","1":"47.618314","business_lat":"47.618314","2":"-122.347998","business_lon":"-122.347998","3":"23.0298400562551","distance":"23.0298400562551"},{"0":"19","business_id":"19","1":"41.248662","business_lat":"41.248662","2":"-96.098760","business_lon":"-96.098760","3":"23.0298400562551","distance":"23.0298400562551"},{"0":"21","business_id":"21","1":"41.273084","business_lat":"41.273084","2":"-95.987816","business_lon":"-95.987816","3":"23.0298400562551","distance":"23.0298400562551"}]
```

Edits

```
 try {

           double lat1 = 37.3324083200000000;
           String lat = Double.toString(lat1);

           double lon1 = -122.0304781500000000;
           String lon = Double.toString(lon1);

           double dist1 = 25;
           String dist = Double.toString(dist1);

           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",lat));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon",lon));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dist",dist));




 LOGIN_URL, "GET", params);
```

New Error

```
08-07 00:24:09.567: E/JSON Parser(9658): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"3":"23.0298400562551","2":"-122.078916","distance":"23.0298400562551","business_lon":"-122.078916","1":"37.393885","0":"3","business_lat":"37.393885","business_id":"3"},{"3":"23.0298400562551","2":"-122.095528","distance":"23.0298400562551","business_lon":"-122.095528","1":"37.394011","0":"5","business_lat":"37.394011","business_id":"5"},{"3":"23.0298400562551","2":"-122.042034","distance":"23.0298400562551","business_lon":"-122.042034","1":"37.390038","0":"7","business_lat":"37.390038","business_id":"7"},{"3":"23.0298400562551","2":"-117.168326","distance":"23.0298400562551","business_lon":"-117.168326","1":"32.723831","0":"9","business_lat":"32.723831","business_id":"9"},{"3":"23.0298400562551","2":"-122.284985","distance":"23.0298400562551","business_lon":"-122.284985","1":"47.557704","0":"11","business_lat":"47.557704","business_id":"11"},{"3":"23.0298400562551","2":"-122.313985","distance":"23.0298400562551","business_lon":"-122.313985","1":"47.614005","0":"13","business_lat":"47.614005","business_id":"13"},{"3":"23.0298400562551","2":"-122.354092","distance":"23.0298400562551","business_lon":"-122.354092","1":"47.672670","0":"15","business_lat":"47.672670","business_id":"15"},{"3":"23.0298400562551","2":"-122.347998","distance":"23.0298400562551","business_lon":"-122.347998","1":"47.618314","0":"17","business_lat":"47.618314","business_id":"17"},{"3":"23.0298400562551","2":"-96.098760","distance":"23.0298400562551","business_lon":"-96.098760","1":"41.248662","0":"19","business_lat":"41.248662","business_id":"19"},{"3":"23.0298400562551","2":"-95.987816","distance":"23.0298400562551","business_lon":"-95.987816","1":"41.273084","0":"21","business_lat":"41.273084","business_id":"21"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: The error is in your code. Looks like you're sending a line break.

Comment: Yes, the problem is definitely in your PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes needed PHP side**

```
$db = new mysqli("myDatabaseUrl","username","password","username",0,"");
```

should be

```
$db = new mysqli("myDatabaseUrl","username","password","Your_dbname");
```

You are getting this error because the php is generating error before your json output.
You cannot have 0 for port and `""` for socket better leave them alone if you are not running mysql on non standard ports.

mysqli constructor is reference http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

> mysqli::__construct() ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host")
>   [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd
>   = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket =
>   ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )

Also check if the ULR you are sending to php is in correct format. You can echo back the requested URL using the following command before the `if` block and the script will return just the URL.

```
die($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

**Changes needed Java side**

PHP code is sending JSONArray of JSONObject, try to convert to json array.

```
 JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(json);.
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to just remove those two fields and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: what is the `url` string?

Comment: your PHP part is fine. your `json` looks perfect.

Comment: Is there a way to see the url that the app is creating

Comment: try to put `die($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);` before the `if` block and the script will return just the URL and check what is the response you are getting. Note: this will be just the requested URL (Not Json).

Comment: that worked perfect thanks. It led to kind of a break through it was not puting any numbers in the url so I converted them from Doubles to Strings and it worked. But now it just putting all my json in an error.

Comment: Your PHP code is sending JSONArray of JSONObject, try to convert to json array `JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(json);`. I am not an expert in java an i cannot even test java part. So this is like a blind recommendation.

Comment: I did some research and your right  I use a for loop to do it so I'm gonna research that a bit. But technically you lead me down the road to the solulion of my original error so if you could rephrase and post your comments as an answer I'll except it.